# UIAccessibilityContainer in a table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, accessibility

I'm trying to put a custom view inside a `UITableViewCell` which of course lives within a `UITableView`. I want to make this custom view accessible so I need to make it a `UIAccessibilityContainer` (since it contains several visual elements that aren't implemented as their own UIViews).

When I do this, the location of the elements get all messed up whenever the table scrolls. While paging through the elements using VoiceOver, it will automatically scroll the table to attempt to center the selected element on screen, but then the outline of where VoiceOver thinks the element is no longer lines up with where it is visually.

[image: broken]

*Note in the screenshot that the inspector says "Row 4, element 2" but the highlighted area is some random place in Row 7 since that happens to be where Row 4 was before it auto-scrolled the table.*

My thought is that I might have to use `UIAccessibilityPostNotification()` to post a layout change when the table view scrolls, but I don't have to do that when I don't use a `UIAccessibilityContainer` and it feels like I shouldn't have to do it and that the system should be handling this for me - but the fact that `UIAccessibilityElement` needs to have it's `accessibilityFrame` set in screen coordinates does seem to throw a wrinkle into things. (Bonus question: Why the heck is the API designed that way? Why not define the frame relative to the element's container or something like that? Arg.)

Here's the custom view's implementation just in case there's something in here which is causing the problem. For the full project (Xcode 4), [click here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/545670/AccessibilityTest/AccessibilityTest.zip).

```
@implementation CellView
@synthesize row=_row;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_accessibleElements release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)setRow:(NSInteger)newRow
{
    _row = newRow;

    [_accessibleElements release];
    _accessibleElements = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0] retain];

    for (NSInteger i=0; i<=_row; i++) {
        UIAccessibilityElement *element = [[UIAccessibilityElement alloc] initWithAccessibilityContainer:self];
        element.accessibilityValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d, element %d", _row, i];
        [_accessibleElements addObject:element];
        [element release];
    }    

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor lightGrayColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(self.bounds);

    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    NSString *info = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row: %d", _row];
    [info drawAtPoint:CGPointZero withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];

    [[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] setFill];
    NSInteger x=0, y=0;
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<=_row; i++) {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(12+x, 22+y, 30, 30);

        UIAccessibilityElement *element = [_accessibleElements objectAtIndex:i];
        element.accessibilityFrame = [self.window convertRect:[self convertRect:rect toView:self.window] toWindow:nil];

        UIRectFill(rect);
        x += 44;

        if (x >= 300) {
            x = 0;
            y += 37;
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount
{
    return [_accessibleElements count];
}

- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [_accessibleElements objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element
{
    return [_accessibleElements indexOfObject:element];
}

@end
```

**Edit**: I should note that I've tried variations that update the element's `accessibilityFrame` in `-indexOfAccessibilityElement:` and `-accessibilityElementAtIndex:` with the idea that VoiceOver will request the element somehow whenever it needs it and that'd be a nice time to update things. However that doesn't seem to work, either. I was kind of hoping maybe VoiceOver would automatically request things to redraw, but that also doesn't seem to work. (The idea of putting the location setting code in `-drawRect:` comes from something I remember seeing at WWDC about this, but it was unclear to me if that was "best practice" or just happened to be convenient.)

Comment: Have you verified the behavior on the actual device and not just a bug in the simulator?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work correctly on device, either. It behaves a bit differently, but still not the way I'd expect.

Comment: I know this is crazy old. Just in case anyone else will stumble over this today: iOS 10 introduced `accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace` which should solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem you described by adding some side effects to the accessibility methods and with collaboration from the table scroll delegates. Inside the `drawRect` method I calculate the *local* coordinates of the rectangle, so I don't need to convert the coordinates there, simply calculate them with regards to the cell's top left corner.

Then, I modified the accessor to update the frame with a side effect like this (note the **y** resetting):

```
- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    UIAccessibilityElement *element = [accesible_items_ get:index];
    CGRect rect = element.accessibilityFrame;
    rect.origin.y = 0;
    element.accessibilityFrame = [self.window
        convertRect:rect fromView:self];
    return element;
}
```

While this works fine for the initial view, you still get the *displaced* frames when the user scrolls, so in your table view controller implement the following scrolling delegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // This loop has a side effects, see the cell accesor code.
    for (id cell in self.tableView.visibleCells)
        for (int f = 0; [cell accessibilityElementAtIndex:f]; f++);

    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(
        UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, nil);
    NSLog(@"Layout changed after scrollViewDidScroll");
}
```

Depending on the contents of your table not all cells may respond to the accessibility method, so you could first query each cell with `respondsToSelector` to avoid sending unexpected messages.

I would also post `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` at the end of the cell setter creating the `UIAccessibilityElement` objects, or you will get log messages saying that your elements disappeared or could not be found.

These changes make the scroll work when iterating the elements one through one with the rotor, but you may get still odd results if the user scrolls with a triple finger gesture. That's because by default tableViews scroll a screen page at a time, which may not happen to have the same element boundaries as your cells, and the rotor selects a cell half visible. Depending on the scrolling direction and other UI elements, the half visible cell could overlap controls the rotor gets confused with. You need to implement paged scrolling to control avoid this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Is this problem affecting the usability of the app in VoiceOver mode? When I've played with VoiceOver on both Mac OS and iOS, the highlight boxes (especially in Web views) frequently become unmatched with their onscreen objects. If the app is still usable in VoiceOver, I'd call this a known bug and fix it if somebody complains.

After all, most of the blind people I know aren't looking at the highlight boxes.

Comment: There are another types of assistive technologies that is visible to users. For example Switch Control allows to control iPhone by external device like keyboard, some kind of sensor or even by facial mimic! Switch Control users needs correct frames of elements